# Hot Chocolate: filtering with a char field

Tags: .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

How can I set up Hot Chocolate filtering to work when a class has a `char` field?

I have a class with a `Status` field of type `char`. Strangely, it seems that **Hot Chocolate does not work with `char` fields**. To get it to even generate a schema I had to configure `AddGraphQLServer()` like this:

```
builder.BindRuntimeType<char, StringType>()
```

and then to get queries to work I had to do this:

```
builder.AddTypeConverter<char, string>(_ => _.ToString())
```

(I presume I will need `AddTypeConverter<string, char>` for mutations.)

But **filtering does not work**. If I add `[UseFiltering]` to a resolver, I can no longer even generate a schema. The error I get is

```
The type of the member Status of the declaring type Offer is unknown
```

**What is the simplest way to get filtering to work** here? I have read some slightly out-of-date inforamtion about `IFilterConvention` but haven't been able to get anything working. I hope this very simple thing (which really should work out of the box) will require only a little bit more code.

Comment: This is .net 6, HC 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a bit awkward, since `char` is not a first-class GraphQL type. We added converters to convert between `char` and `string`, and added a custom filter convention so we could filter by char.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        // Add our custom conventions for filtering
        .AddConvention<IFilterConvention, CustomFilterConvention>()
        // Add support for char (treat as string)
        .BindRuntimeType<char, StringType>()
        .AddTypeConverter<char, string>(_ => _.ToString())
        .AddTypeConverter<string, char>(_ => _[0])
        // Add support for char? (treat as string)
        .BindRuntimeType<char?, StringType>()
        .AddTypeConverter<char?, string>(_ => _?.ToString() ?? "")
        .AddTypeConverter<string, char?>(_ => _[0])
        // ...etc
}

public class CustomFilterConvention : FilterConvention
{
    protected override void Configure(IFilterConventionDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        base.Configure(descriptor);

        descriptor.BindRuntimeType<char, ComparableOperationFilterInputType<char>>();
        descriptor.BindRuntimeType<char?, ComparableOperationFilterInputType<char?>>();
        descriptor.AddDefaults();
        descriptor.Provider(new QueryableFilterProvider(_ => _.AddDefaultFieldHandlers()));
    }
}
```

I think a better approach might be to just change our entity class to use `string` instead of `char`. Might try that later.